# How do I get every possible UInt8 array combination up to a certain array size?

Tags: arrays, swift, uint8array

I am trying to get every possible UInt8 array up to an array size of 100 in Swift. So far, I have the following code:

```
var arrays = [[UInt8]]()
for size in 1...100 {
    let arr = Array(repeating: 255, count: size) as [UInt8]
    arrays.append(arr)
}
```

The code so far just creates an array filled with `255` how many ever times specified by the for loop. Instead, I want the code to create an array for every array size that lists all possible combinations. For example, when `size` is one, the arrays should look like the following:

```
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], so on until [255]
```

And when `size` is two, the arrays should look like this:

```
[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], so on until [0,255]
[1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], so on until [1,255]
```

This should continue up to where `size` is 100. Is there any way that I can accomplish this using Swift?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `as [UInt8]?` mean? There is no optional

Comment: @vadian That was an accident, it has been corrected now. It is not supposed to be an optional, but is supposed to convert to a UInt8 array instead of the default Int array.

Comment: If you want to generate `[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]...`, you need to write some _code_ that generates `[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]...`. Do not write some code that does something totally different and then complain that it does not do what you want. Your current code is almost completely unrelated to your stated goal.

Comment: I recommend tackling the problem in little pieces. Figure out how to generate `[0,1,2,3]`. Then how to generate `[[0], [1], [2], [3]]`. Then how to generate `[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3]]`. And so on.

Comment: Unless this is for some homework I recommend using [Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms)

Comment: Note that for an array with 100 elements, there will be `100!` (100 factorial) possible orders of those elements. That's about 9.33 x 10^153. Or 9 followed by 153 zeros. It will take a **long** time to run, and will generate an appalling amount of output. You likely don't have a storage device big enough to save all 9.33E153 arrays, nor could you afford enough cloud storage to save the output.

Comment: @DuncanC actually `(1...100).combinations(ofCount: 2)` is pretty fast

Comment: Yes, but the OP said "I am trying to get every possible UInt8 array up to an array size of 100".

Comment: I had to try :D. still pretty fast (and lazy!) with algorithms, but `Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: arithmetic overflow` when trying to get the count...

Answer (score 1):

These kind of problems can now be tackled with [Swift Algorithms](https://swift.org/blog/swift-algorithms/).

see [`combinations(ofCount:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Combinations.md) :

```
import Algorithms

let combinations = (1...5).combinations(ofCount: 2)
combinations.forEach { combination in
    print(combination)
}
```

output:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[4, 5]
```